# Python code is taking very long time while creating JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am using python 2.6.6 version and wrote the code to create JSON file reading data from Oracle table shown below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import cx_Oracle
import collections
from collections import OrderedDict
import sys
import os
import logging
from datetime import datetime

connstr = u'username/password@dbname'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
r_cursor = conn.cursor()
r_cursor.execute("sql query")
prows = r_cursor.fetchall()
objects_list = []

for prow in prows:
    p = collections.OrderedDict()
    p['col1'] = prow[0]
    p['col2'] = prow[1]
    p['col3'] = prow[2]
    p['col4'] = prow[3]
    p['col5'] = prow[4]
    #This is to filter the null columns
    pf = OrderedDict((k, v) for (k, v) in p.iteritems()
                        if v not in ('None', None))
    objects_list.append(pf)

if len(objects_list)>0:
    ef['name'] = objects_list
else:
    pass

j = json.dumps(ef,indent=2)
objects_file = 'filename.js'
f = open(objects_file,'w')
print >> f,j
conn.close()
f.close()
```

When reading with 100 k records it is very fast and completing in 5 secs but when reading data with `1.5 million` taking 15 mins.
I tried giving `prows = r_cursor.fetcmany(100000)` then it is completed very fast with only `100000` records and coming out.
Could you please suggest how to read the data each time `100000` records and loop it for next records. I heard `generator` will work on that way. Could you please suggest how to use generator here?

Comment: But are you trying to put it all in a single file? Your I/O problems will get worse if you have to keep reading it back in and I'm not sure you'd get valid json at the end.

Comment: Actually, where is the bottleneck here? Are you hitting your max RAM?

Comment: You need to fix your indentation and quotations, your code is difficult to read

Comment: Can you repeatedly call `r_cursor.fetcmany(100000)` to incrementally get the each batch of records?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but how about writing this instead too?

```
prow = [None, 1, 2, 3, 4]
collections.OrderedDict(('col{}'.format(i+1), prow[i]) for i in range(5) if prow[i] not in ("None",None))
```

Returns:

```
OrderedDict([('col2', 1), ('col3', 2), ('col4', 3), ('col5', 4)])
```